# VPS with Ubuntu 20.04: Cannot connect to Github

Tags: ubuntu, github, vps, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I am setting up a VPS that should host an RStudio instance and shiny server.

It seems that I have trouble with communicating especially to Github. I have set up a Git repository and wanted to test it:

```
git push -u origin master
fatal: konnte nicht auf 'https://github.com/***.git/' zugreifen: Couldn't connect to server
```

Similarly when I am trying to install an R library from Github.

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github('***')\""
Fehler: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
Couldn't connect to server
```

I disabled the ufw, but no change. Any ideas on what yould help?

Also: Not sure if related but installing RStudio server yields an error as well:

```
sudo rstudio-server verify-installation
ERROR system error 1 (Operation not permitted); OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::setResourceLimit(rstudio::core::system::ResourceLimit, RLimitType, RLimitType) src/cpp/core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:1485; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) src/cpp/server/ServerMain.cpp:569
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer: The VPS runs on IPv6 which currently is not supported by Github.